# how to see javadoc using command line

Tags: java, command-line

In `WINDOWS` platform, using command line (`cmd`), I can see the methods belong to a specific package. Say, I want to see the members of `Random` class. I can see them entering the following command:

```
javap -p java.util.Random
```

But, how to see the documentation belongs to each of its members/methods?
More specifically:

> Is there anyway to see the javadoc from cmd? if yes, what is it? if no, how could you be sure?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to know where to find the generated documentation?

Comment: Such a command line would have to launch a browser. Javadoc is HTML. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @EJP I wanted to know that "is there anyway to see the javadoc from cmd? if yes, what is it?" May be it is more clarified.

Comment: But why would you want to do that? Of course it is possible _somehow_, but it would be unnecessarily difficult for _reading_ purposes.

Comment: The objective behind this is a little bit funny, but necessary. Our ``JAVA`` course teacher told us that he would take our lab exam allowing only ``notepad++`` and ``cmd``. It is difficult to keep in mind a lot of java methods and their works. So, we need some alternatives which would be permissible. @Boris

Comment: You should explain this in your question.

Comment: @manetsus I understood your question, and I answered it, to the extent that it can be answered. If your teacher is expecting you to produce Javadoc without a browser to check it with, he is setting a pointless constraint. Maybe he is expecting you not to *read* Javadoc, i.e. memorise the APIs you are to use, which is unrealistic if not quite pointless. I've had browser tabs open at Javadoc for 18 years. You should ask him for clarification.

Comment: Of course you can always browse those online docs with a cli browser like [elinks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/elinks.1.html), but I agree that something like the help in python would be desirable, but I haven't yet heard of any such thing for Java.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. And most certainly not with `javap`. As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) says (it's the title to be more precise):

> javap - The Java Class File Disassembler

Or in other words: javap doesn't load any docs, it disassembles the .class file containing the specified class. Apart from that it wouldn't make any sense to include a commandlinetool for showing the docs. It's not practical and the docs already exist online.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to see the javadoc from cmd?

No, there is no easy way to see Javadoc from cmd.

> if no, how could you be sure?

Because, it needs internet connection and Javadoc is loaded from corresponding server. On the other hand, member classes are accessed from `.class` file. That means this service is available if you don't have internet connection. But Javadoc is impossible without internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your post, is to use "lynx, links",  cli web browser to load the javadoc html pages.

1. For a full cli development (offline or online),
2. From your favorite shell, I suggest using "gnu-screen" to be able to switch between multiple terminals that offer the function of a DEC VT100 terminal. There is a scrollback
    history buffer for each virtual terminal and a copy-and-paste mechanism that allows moving text
3. regions between windows.
4. In one of the terminal, I compile and run using "javac, java or jdb(javadebug)".
5. For example, javac  -cp ~/java/jnetpcap.jar:.:$HOME/lib FGjnetPcapFile.java ; java -cp ~/java/jnetpcap.jar:.:$HOME/lib FGjnetPcapFile ; jdb -classpath ~/java/jnetpcap.jar:.:    $HOME/lib FGjnetPcapFile
6. In a second terminal, I use "lynx" to view the java documentation.  Note that the "javadoc" tool creates html format documentation.
7. It is not used to view the documentation unlike perldoc.
8. The java documentation can be part of the jre, the jdk or even downloaded as a javadoc-xxx.jar file.  In jre and jdk, it is already uncompressed and stored on disk as html files.  ex: /usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-headless/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/index-all.html
9. In case of a javadoc-xxx.jar file, you can unzip the file with "unzip", then use "lynx" to access the html files extracted.
10. In the third terminal, I use "vim" to create or modify the code.
11. Finally, in a fourth terminal, I use "svn" as a code revision control, and vimdiff as visual comparison tool.

I also plan to use gnuit "Gnu Interactive tools"